# Time event every predefined time (15min )

Tags: c#, events, datetime, timer, intervals

I have a problem and i cannot seem to work my way around it.
All i want is to fire an event at a predefined time depending on the system clock for example every 15 minutes 30 minutes or 1 hour for example.

I would preferably do this without using c# timers.

A more explanation is that for example the user choses a polling time of 15 minutes and the current time is 8:49.

The event will fire at 9:04 without lagging.

Can this be done without system timers.

Comment: Well I don't really know much about hooking but it might be possible to hook system time functions to achieve what you want.

Comment: Just use a timer, and maintain them well for each user poll...  No lagging will happen if you are starting and stopping your timers correctly..

Comment: To find a 'better' solution than using a Timer (and usually one should be enough!) you must explain just what you don't like about them?! They are meant to do just what you want, so where is the problem?

Comment: I made the application with timers. It polls every 900s for example which is equal to 15 minutes and i noticed that it lagged a few seconds.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for solving this problem:

- Using a timer control. The simplest way to do
- Using the static method `Thread.Sleep(int milliseconds)`. Using this method there is a little problem because the method block the thread tha launch `Thread.Sleep(int)`. For example if you launch this in the main thread the method will block it. So for solving this problem you can create a new thread and thene make the `Thread.Sleep(int ms)` in the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this match your needs, but if you have to schedule a lot of jobs / events then Quartz.NET may be the right choice

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/features.html